# What do we have in the bytes beginning at the "Address of a function"?How to know how many bytes to consider?

Tags: c, function, function-pointers, sizeof

My brain gets numb just even imagining this.So bear with me if my question is  little wordy.So I've sliced my question into parts.

**1)** What do we have at the at the bits/bytes starting at the **address of the function**?I mean,at an integer variable's address, we visualize 4 bytes(for 32 bit systems) of 1's and 0's that represent the number in binary form.For a character variable we visualize a single byte with the ASCII value of the character.For a `double` we visualize 8 bytes accordingly.But what on earth should I visualize at the bytes starting with the address of a function?I know that a call stack is created when a function is invoked,but what about the function itself?At its address do we have the function's expressions,`if`s,`loops`, etc in binary form?Are those bits/bytes representing a function too complicated to visualize by a human unlike say `integers`?

**2)** Can we use `sizeof` for a function?Why or why can't we?If we have no idea how to determine the size allocated to a function, then how do functions have addresses?As if they have addresses,they must have size and since we have pointers to functions, how is it determined by the pointers how many bytes to interpret starting with pointer address?After all we can use those pointers to invoke the functions.

Please be generous with the details.Books and Google hasn't been helpful at all in this regard.

Comment: Is your question about C? Or is it about some specific implementation or platform? Because it doesn't seem to be about C. And if it's about an implementation or platform, you haven't told us which one.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It's about functions in C Mr.Schwartz.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Though it could be considered a generic question for all related langauges,and a generic answer would do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It can be anything at all. It is not required to be anything specific.
2. No. A function's address is just the entry point. There's no requirement that it, for example, even occupy consecutive memory locations.

Usually, the function address is where the actual machine code for that function begins. There's no reliable way to tell where the function ends. Some platforms might lay out functions as they appear in the source code, one after the other. But other platforms, particularly ones with [IPO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocedural_optimization), won't be nearly as simple.

Comment: Please add some further details Mr Schwartz.

Comment: What details were you looking for?

Comment: @tangrs Just some further elaboration on what Mr.Schwartz told.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I am still trying to understand every word of it.

Answer (score 1):

In most C implementations, a pointer to a function is implemented as an address of the start of the function’s machine code. The bytes at that address are the bytes of the instructions that are executed when the function is called.

In some implementations, a pointer to a function is implemented as an address of data about the function, such as data that contains the address of the machine code and a description of the function’s parameters or register use.

This answer is just for educational purposes, because these details are not part of the C standard and vary between implementations.

Answer (score 1):

1.
I usually visualize the memory pointed to by a function pointer as the assembler mnemonics themselves instead of a stream of bytes. If you're on a architecture with fixed-width instructions, you can visualize it as an array of integers - each encoding a different instruction.

2.
No, you can't. There's some great answers on SO that explain why you can't `sizeof()` a function but it basically boils down to the fact that code for that function isn't guaranteed to be all together so it's impossible to determine the size. A compiler could emit instructions that jump into another functions if it wanted to (ironically, this is exactly what happens when you call a function or evoke a function pointer ;) ).

It is perfectly possible and valid to have an address of something and not know its size - just look at a `void` pointer for example. Just as we don't know the size of the data a `void` pointer points to, we don't know the size of code that a function pointer points to.